# Rounded corners on bootstrap modal div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a .NET page that is using some Bootstrap markup to create a div that is later used as a popup modal. I want to round the corners. While modifying the CSS seems to effect the border width and color, I cannot make border-radius work. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="productModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="productModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog ui-corner-all">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="productModalLabel">Product</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="contentDiv">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="orderClose">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="orderSave">Save Changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My JQuery calls a webservice that builds HTML and inserts int into #contentDiv and that works just fine. Here is my CSS for the rounded corners:

```
.modal-header {
    padding:9px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #0480be;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 100px;
     border-top-left-radius: 100px;
     border-top-right-radius: 100px;
 }


.modal-header {
    padding:9px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #0480be;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 100px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
     border-top-right-radius: 100px;
 }

.modal-dialog {
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    width: 900px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
     border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Why won't border-radius work? I have changed the number to some drastic things to see if it makes a difference but nothing changes. As stated, I can change anything in the border reference or the width reference and see the changes, so it is seeing the .modal-dialog class. any ideas here?

Comment: With dev tools i found that border-radius: 6px; is applied to .modal-content and not to .modal-header and .modal-dialog.

Comment: For anyone who is looking to remove the rounded corners from the modal you can add `border-radius: 0;` to `.modal-content` in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

The answer was actually obvious but I was NOT thinking clearly. All I had to do was add !important after each line because the bootstrap.css was taking precendence. Once I added !important the problem was solved instantly. Just thought I would add this in case someone else has this problem in the future.

Comment: You may want to consider adding your custom CSS file after the Bootstrap.css file. This will prevent you from having to use !important statements, which are frowned upon and can cause issues with troubleshooting in the future.